# How to make this json object to an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this json, which I want to convert to an array.

```
{  
    "match1": {
      "team1": "2",
      "team2": "0"
    },
    "match2": {
      "team1": "3",
      "team2": "1"
    }  
}
```

so far after searching and looking for simillar questions, I have come up with this

```js
var data = {
  "match1": {
    "team1": "2",
    "team2": "0"
  },
  "match2": {
    "team1": "3",
    "team2": "1"
  }
}

const array = Object.values(data.match1).map((key) => [key, data[key]]);

console.log(array);

// outputs 
//[2, , 0, ]
```

It looks fine but it needs me to write for each 'match' property and I need a way to output them together as the match property can be many e.g match3, match4 e.t.c. also not sure why the double comma?

so the expected output I want is

```
[[2,0], [3,1]];
```

how to do it?

Comment: That isn't JSON, that's an object.

Comment: Please read the usage description of the `json` tag.

Comment: To this issue: why did you expect the callback of `Object.values` to be a *key*? There is `Object.keys` for that.

Comment: I am getting it from api though

Comment: That might be, but your question is not about the text you receive, but about an object you already have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var data = {  
    "match1": {
      "team1": "2",
      "team2": "0"
    },
    "match2": {
      "team1": "3",
      "team2": "1"
    }  
}

var result = Object.keys(data).map(key => Object.values(data[key]))

console.log(result)
```

If you want get values as number

```
var result = Object.keys(data).map(key => Object.values(data[key]).map(string  => parseInt(string)))
```

Comment: The only technicality is that their desired output appear to be numbers rather than strings, but that's a trivial to fix

Comment: It’s possible that neither the matches nor the teams will be in the expected order.

Comment: This could be reduce to: `Object.values(data).map(o => Object.values(o))` without the mapping to numbers. But is nice +1!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var data = {"match1": {"team1": "2","team2": "0"},"match2": {"team1": "3","team2": "1"}}

var result = Object.values(data).map( val => Object.values(val) )

console.log(result);
```